# Problems with $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I am doing some checks on my website to assure that the web browser can run it. If the browser pass the requirements, I want to reload the webpage and send a post argument with jQuery like this.

I have tried the `$.post` function on jQuery like this:

```
$.post("index.php", { 
  correcto_obligatorio: true 
});

window.location.reload("index.php")
```

However, when the browser reloads the web, there is no `correcto_obligatorio` parameter on `$_POST`. I used the `var_dump` php function to print it and all I get is `NULL`

Comment: That's because the `$.post` is asynchronius, so the post is sent - but you appear to not do anything with it

Comment: You seem to be a little confused as to how these things work. [`.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) can have a parameter, but it is a boolean that forces the current page to be reloaded from the server rather than the browser cache

Comment: You are using AJAX. The reason why one should use AJAX is to perform asynchronous http requests WITHOUT reloading the page. If you want to perform a traditional POST (reloading the page) you should use a `<form>`

Comment: We should also ask, although its a little irrelevant at this point, but what does `index.php` do with the data that you send it in `correcto_obligatorio: true` Primarily, how does it persist that data

Comment: Is the script that contains this code called `index.php` or is it another script completely? The reason for asking is that `window.location.reload("index.php")` wont redirect to `index.php` the `.reload()` will only reload the current page, whatever that is

Answer (score 3):

$.post is a separate asynchronous request. 
window.location.reload just reloads a page, but doesn't consider all of your async requests.

If you print $_POST['correcto_obligatorio'] not with `var_dump`, but log to file you will see the value there.

There is two solutions for you.

1) Await for the ajax result and respond to it.

```
$.post( "index.php", { 
  correcto_obligatorio: true 
}, function (data) {
  if (data.passed_validation) {
    window.location.reload("index.php")
  }
});
```

2) Second is to post a form

```
<form action="/index.php" method="POST" id="my_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="correcto_obligatorio" value="1"/>
</form>

<script>
  function myFunc() {
     $("#my_form").submit()
  }
</script>
```

The most common and rightful one is the first solution.

Comment: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56338728/problems-with-post#comment99283434_56338728)

Answer (score 0):

your code does not wait for the post to finish. You basically send the request and redirect the browser to index.php without waiting for the server to answer you. Consider using a callback function:

```
$.post( "index.php",  { 
  correcto_obligatorio: true
}, function( result) {
    if (result.passed) {
        window.location.reload("index.php")
    }
});
```

That is assuming that the server responds with a valid json object that contains the parameter passed (content type should be set to application/json )